# How to post on Facebook page's wall in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I want to post any message or link to an Facebook page.What I have tried is this.

```
void postInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", messageFacebook);
            parameters.putString("name", "Test Name");
            parameters.putString("link", "http://www.mylink.com/");
            parameters.putString("picture", imageUrl);
            parameters.putString("display", "page");

            String responsePost = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            String responsePagePost = facebook.request(FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID+"/feed", parameters, "POST");

            Log.i(TAG, "responsePost = " + responsePost);
            Log.i(TAG, "responsePagePost = " + responsePagePost);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What I am doing is I am posting a link to user's wall & also to my app's Facebook page.
This code works fine but problem is on Facebook page.The link which I post on Facebook page doesn't appear on page's wall but it appears on page's timeline in a box titled "*Recent Posts by Others on MyApp Page*".

I want the post should appear on wall rather than timeline.

What should I do I am not getting please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has changed all it's profiles to timelines now. Any facebook page will show posts by others as "Recent Posts by Others on MyApp Page". This behavior is controlled by facebook and not by your app. There is nothing you can do in this case.

Comment: If I am posting to my own page how can make it to display on my page's wall

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
void postInfo()
  {
    try
    {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", messageFacebook);
        parameters.putString("name", "Test Name");
        parameters.putString("link", "http://www.mylink.com/");
        parameters.putString("picture", imageUrl);
        parameters.putString("display", "page");

        facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", params,
                new DialogListener() {

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                    }

                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                });
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```