# How to post on the Wall of a page using Facebook Android SDK 3.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have an App page at fb.com/my_own_app_page. Now using the Facebook SDK for Android I would like to post on the wall of fb.com/my_own_app_page. How do I achieve that?

As the graph path is set to `"me/feed"` to post on our own wall, I tried changing it to `"my_own_app_page"` as well as `"my_own_app_page/feed"` but none of these worked.

Can you please give the solution if it is possible?

Comment: Did you see the answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969224/how-to-post-on-facebook-pages-wall-in-android. Facebook has changed all it's profiles to timelines now. Any facebook page will show posts by others as "Recent Posts by Others on MyApp Page". This behavior is controlled by facebook and not by your app. There is nothing you can do in this case.